# How do I update fields in a web form with SOAP and PHP?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I've been tasked with creating a web form that operates like a calculator, in that the user needs to enter some numbers and then the form is supposed to retrieve a particular sales tax rate, apply it to the entered figures and then provide a resulting number. I've been given an XML document to retrieve the sales tax number that is formatted as SOAP envelopes. I've never used SOAP before. I'm definitely in over my head.

First of all, is this possible?

Secondly, I know this is probably fairly complicated guess what I'm asking for is just some pointers to either the specific types of techniques that I need to research or some good tutorials learn how to do this...?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible! Do you have the url of the wsdl?

Comment: I don't....I was trying to figure out if the WSDL is something I need to generate and put on the server. It's not the same thing as the XML file with the SOAP envelopes I've been given, is it? Here's a sample from the file...


`<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
       <update xmlns="urn:messages_2012_1.xxxx.xxx.xxxx">
           <record internalId="748586" xsi:type="q1:Customer" xmlns:q1="urn:relationships_2012_1.lists.webservices.xxxxxx.com">`

Comment: Is this XML document you were given not gonna change? or it's a dynamic one?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I'm not sure...the document looks like it has actual data in it, which makes me think this is just a template of something that should be dynamic.

I'm wondering if it would make the most sense right now to ask for a WSDL document instead of this XML file? Would that be a logical next step?

I feel a bit sheepish, because I've never worked with SOAP before and and I'm not sure whether I should try to figure this out or whether it's just going to be over my head. :-/ I have basic to moderate PHP skills. Is this going to be an easy nut to crack or fairly complicated?

Comment: Well if it gonna be a dynamic data, provided by a third party, I suggest you try using Soap. If it is a static data, you can just parse the XML you've been provided using `SimpleXML`. About the level of difficulty, well if you gonna have to code the server side, it's a bit complicated, but if you need only to consume the webservice, it's not very difficult.

Comment: The agreement was that I would just be consuming the webservice. I did not agree that I would be writing any server side coding. So does that mean that I just need a WSDL address?

Comment: Yes exactly, once you have that, you'll need to make a `SoapClient` call, and retrive the data you need. You can find many examples of that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your provider for the WSDL adress, then make a soap call [SoapClient::__soapCall](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapcall.php)

You might also need to use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to test the webservice.